# Why do I get an error when trying to serializing JSON in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, serialization, swift2, nsjsonserialization

I just starting to learn swift. So I am a noob if it comes to swift. To try and practice it I am trying to make a grocery application for ios. But now I am stuck on probably one of the most basic things, serializing a JSON object without using a library so just with the standard swift code. So my question is can you help me solving my problem with serializing the data that I got from the api.

I am using postman to check what kind of response I get from the api. When I do a get to the api this is the response I get:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Regular List"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "List for diner"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "List 3"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "List for next week"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Test name"
  }
]
```

In my swift code I am trying to get this response by doing this:

```
func getBoodschapListJSON(){
        let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let userId = prefs.integerForKey("UserId")
        let requestUrl = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8080/api/lists/user/id/\(userId)")!
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestUrl)
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

                do {
                    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)

                    //Here comes some code to try and process the JSON object in the table View.
                } catch {
                    print("error serializing JSON: \(error)")
                }

        }).resume()
    }
```

But I never got a valid response I end up with the error: 
"error serializing JSON: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}"

I expect that it has something to do with the JSON not being in the right format so that NSJSONSerialization is able to interpret it. But I am not sure, I have looked at a several stack-overflow posts that had the same question as I have. Most of them said to use .AllowFragments but that did not resolve my error.

Would anyone be so kind to help me so I able to fix this error in my code?

Comment: Please check weather your json from server is in correct format. You can check the same on jsonlint.com or any other json validator.

Comment: @ArunGupta I checked it with jsonlint.com, it is valid json. I had my doubts if the method that I call: "try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)" is able to interpreter the json that is returned by the api. I think I used the correct parameters but I am a noob so errors are easily made.

Comment: Can you post the folder "set up" and your API's code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL looks a bit weird, but it is still possible for it to work like that. Try visit the URL in your browser (set an id for userId) and make sure it looks all right. If it does, make sure there is no html in your API's code. For example no meta tags (which you might be using).

If that doesn't work, maybe it's the code. Try mine:

```
let urlAsString = "http://localhost:8080/api/lists/user/id/\(userId)"
do {
    let jsonDict: NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
    print (jsonDict)
}
catch {
    print ("Couldn't get JSON... \(error)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advise. I really thought that It cannot be the URL because I have checked it a several times. Now I checked it in the browser and I noticed I did not get a response. Guess I still had an error in there I hate it when this occurs to me. I really thought that the code was wrong but in the end it was the url. But now I wonder, what code is better, yours or mine? Because both are working now and I would like to use the best practice.

Comment: @user3473161 I don't know, I don't think there's a big difference. For me, who have used my version, think mine is easier. Choose what you want! :)

Comment: @user3473161 I found a new JSON code. It's much shorter and less complicated. I'm pretty sure this one is the best

Comment: That looks great, from now on I am going to use that piece of code. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

use this Simple code to get a jSon Array

```
   let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "your URL")!)


        let jsonArray: NSArray = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSArray
```

After that Convert this array to NSDictionary and use its Values.. A sample to convert into Dictionary is

```
 let cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("atCell")! as UITableViewCell

        let maindata = (data[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary)
        cell.textLabel?.text = maindata["date"] as? String
```

p.s I used  a table View to show the data...